# AWS Eventbridge doesn't trigger the targets which use input transformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm, aws-event-bridge

I have an Eventbridge rule which has two targets. One target is a CloudWatch log group and other is an SSM Automation (document). Rule triggers and both the targets show expected results.

But as soon as I change the input (Eventbridge > SSM Automation) from Constant to using Input Transformer, the SSM Automation is never triggered. I am sure Eventbridge rule gets triggered because the log group gets the log, but can't figure out why the SSM Automation isn't getting triggered with an input transformer.